# Custom Option Price Calculation Method

Tags: cart, price, catalog

Can someone explain **why a custom option of type `percent` is calculated using the final item price** on a quote?

See here:

```
# File: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Value.php
public function getPrice($flag=false)
{
    if ($flag && $this->getPriceType() == 'percent') {
        $basePrice = $this->getOption()->getProduct()->getFinalPrice();
        $price = $basePrice*($this->_getData('price')/100);
        return $price;
    }
    return $this->_getData('price');
}
```

It doesn't seem to make sense to do this. Here's an example to illustrate the problem:

```
Laptop Computer
---
  Price: 500.00

  Custom Options
  ---
  1-YR Warranty: 20%
```

As I attempt to add this item to my cart along with the warranty option, my total cost as shown on the product view page will be `600.00`. That looks good, because `20%` is applied to the final price of `600.00` at that moment (`100.00`).

But what happens in the cart if this method is called, after the option has already been applied to the item?

According to the `getPrice` method above, it will show as `120.00` (`20%` of `600.00`) ... clearly this is not right. And curiously, a stock installation of CE 1.x does not render custom option prices in the cart (only row totals).

Has anybody encountered this before? Or maybe more likely, what am I not understanding correctly here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shouldn't happen. The method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option_Value::getPrice()` is called *during* calculation of the products final price. At the beginning of this calculation "final_price" is set to the base price (1) and then incrementally modified, this includes adding option prices (2):

```
    /**
     * Get product final price
     *
     * @param   double $qty
     * @param   Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
     * @return  double
     */
    public function getFinalPrice($qty = null, $product)
    {
        if (is_null($qty) && !is_null($product->getCalculatedFinalPrice())) {
            return $product->getCalculatedFinalPrice();
        }

(1)===> $finalPrice = $this->getBasePrice($product, $qty); <===
        $product->setFinalPrice($finalPrice);
        Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_get_final_price', array('product' => $product, 'qty' => $qty));
        $finalPrice = $product->getData('final_price');

(2)===> $finalPrice = $this->_applyOptionsPrice($product, $qty, $finalPrice); <===
        $finalPrice += $this->getTotalBundleItemsPrice($product, $qty);

        $product->setFinalPrice($finalPrice);
        return max(0, $product->getData('final_price'));
    }
```

### Update

For those who don't read comments and want an answer to **why** the "final price" is used to convert the custom option percent amount: The percentage is actually based upon the base price with applied catalog price rules (or any other rules that custom extensions apply with the event `catalog_product_get_final_price`. This is not the *final* final price.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Your answer possibly reveals a mistake in my scenario. I've attempted to extend `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option_Value` to render item option prices in the cart. At that point the final price has already been calculated. So when I use the `getPrice` method, I end up with the inflated value as shown in my question. In other words, this class was not designed for use where I'm using it.

Although personally I still don't like the idea that calling `getPrice` multiple times may give you a different result.

Comment: I'm on the fence about accepting this answer, as it doesn't cover **why** the final price is used to convert the custom option percent amount. It makes more sense to me that `20%` is always based on the unit cost of the item (base price).

Comment: It is based upon the base price with applied catalog price rules (or any other rules that custom extensions apply with the event `catalog_product_get_final_price`. Doesn't that make sense? The side effect of `getPrice()` is indeed ugly but that's a different topic.

Comment: I hadn't considered the price rules or the reach of that event. In that case, I agree and it does make sense now. As you said, the implementation of `getPrice` is another story. Your comment is worth adding as part of the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
 $productSku = $_product->getSku();
 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
 $productId = $product->getIdBySku( $productSku );
 $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($_product->getId());
 $attVal = $product->getOptions();
 $optStr = "";
?>
<div class="actions">

    <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
        <div class="no-display">
            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
        </div>
       <?php $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); ?>
    <?php $product->load($_product->getId()); ?>

 <?php foreach($attVal as $optionKey => $optionVal)
{
  $optStr.='<dt><label>'.$optionVal->getTitle().'</label></dt>';
  $optStr.= "<select style='display:block; clear:both;' id='".$optionVal->getId()."' name='options[".$optionVal->getId()."]'>";
  foreach($optionVal->getValues() as $valuesKey => $valuesVal)
{
$price = number_format($valuesVal->getPrice(),0);
$optStr.= "<option price='".number_format($valuesVal->getPrice(),0)."' data-label='".$colorarray[$valuesVal->getTitle()]."' value='".$valuesVal->getId()."'>".$valuesVal->getTitle(); if($price != '1'){$optStr.=" - Rs.".number_format($valuesVal->getPrice(),2);}$optStr.="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>";
}
$optStr.= "</select>";
}
echo($optStr );
?>
 <?php if($_product->isSaleable()):?>
  <input type="image" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/addtocart.png')?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="addToCart('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')">

<?php else:?>
     <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock')?></span></p>
 <?php endif;?>

 </form>
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post "code only" answers if the question asks for an *explanation*. How is this code supposed to help?